# rectangle size vs window size

Tags: geometry

I always want the large dimension of a rectangle to fill 75% of the small dimension of a window. The rectangle can be any size and the window can be any size. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W$ be a window with real dimensions $W_s, W_l : W_s \leq W_l$.

Let $R$ be a rectangle with real dimensions $R_s, R_l : R_s \leq R_l$.

Then you require it so that $R_l = .75(W_s)$.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you, R small would be a ratio of the original R large to R small?

Comment: The only ratio here is the one you require, that large dimension of rectangle $R_l$ is $\frac{3}{4}$ths the length of the small dimension of the window $W_s$.

Comment: given R-large is 3/4 W-small, how would I get R-small

Comment: You said the dimensions "can be any size", so choose it.

Comment: That's the constant, I see. Thank you for your time.